# C# glass on an mdiparent

Tags: c#, mdi, aero, aero-glass, mdiparent

I am trying to use the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea method on an mdiparent.

```
IsMdiContainer = true;
```

However the glass does not render correctly. Is this a limitation of an mdiparent I can get around? If the form isn't set as an mdicontainer then the glass renders perfectly. The glass area paints white instead of with glass.

Comment: I've tried absolutely everything I can think of to get this to work. Are there wndproc messages I can intercept or something I can do with the NativeWindow object? I need all the functionality of an MDI form just with an larger title bar. Help?

Comment: See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190395/how-to-remove-gray-background-on-mdi-parent-form) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to remove gray background on MDI parent form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190395/how-to-remove-gray-background-on-mdi-parent-form)