# A modal form with a parent form as background

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

How can I have a black form as a background and some modal forms opened one at a time whose owner is the black form? I need these two to retain their order together (when minimized and maximized) that's why I have chosen the modal form.

I have made a simple main form with black background, and opened a form in dialog (modal) form. The main form provides a black background for me and the modal form stays in front of the black background. But when opening new forms, I can't set the owner of new modal form to the aforementioned black form. I have tried passing the black form object and also registering events to no avail.

Do you know any mechanism to implement the following scenario:

A black form as a background and a series of modal forms opened one at a time in front of the black one in a way that the black form is the owner of every modal form.

Thanks

**Edit**

Please consider this scenario: I have 3 forms named **frmBlack**, **Form1** and **Form2**. I use **frmBlack** as the **main blacked form**. After placing a button on this form I call the Form1Object.ShowDialog(this). Now suppose that I want to navigate to the third form (Form2), [this means that I must close the Form1Object] I put a button on the second form (Form1) and when this button is pressed I must close the Form1 object and navigate to the Form2Object while its owner in the ShowDialog() function must be set to frmBlack.

Comment: Making them modal with ShowDialog(owner) doesn't make much sense.  Just use Show(owner) instead.

Comment: It does no make it modal, I need the two to stick together! I may try a simple demo later to clarify my need.

Comment: An owned non-modal window is always displayed on top of the owner.  That's as sticky as you should need.  If you want it *confined* to the owner as well then you need MDI.

Comment: This doesn't go anywhere until you stop using ShowDialog()

Answer (score 0):

This is done using [MDI Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76.aspx).

Your application will look like this: http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AB3/Images/MDI%20Child%20menu.gif

This works in winform projects, not in WPF project (at least not by default).

Comment: I need a single form open at a time and meanwhile I need a black background.

Answer (score 0):

Parent or Owner? That's a difference. Parent is only used in MDI-Applications (see Luigi's post). The owner can be set in the call to `ShowDialog( owningForm )`.

Comment: Owner is what I want. I don't want to get involved in painting the MDI form as stated in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190395/how-to-remove-gray-background-on-mdi-parent-form

Comment: To achieve what you want set the owner in call to ShowDialog (which would be your background window. That's how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want from the window with the second button post pack to the `frmBlack` and let it do the work. Or more specifically set a flag within the `frmBlack`, since in `frm1.btnShowNextForm` you need to close frm1.

And also take a look at `Form.Owner`.

So something along these lines in `frm1.buttonShowNextFormClicked()`:

```
{
   if ( null != Owner )
   {
      FrmBlack frmBlackLocal = Owner as FrmBlack;

      if ( null != frmBlackLocal )
      {
         frmBlackLocal.NextAction = FrmBLack.NextActions.ShowForm2; //an enum
      }
   }

   Close();
}
```

and in frmBlack

```
{

   frm1.ShowDialog(this);

   if ( NextAction == NextActions.ShowForm2)
   {
      frm2.ShowDialog(this);
   }
}
```

Well, of course it needs some brush-up (like extracting the next handler in a function of its own), but you should get the idea.